# How to compare R-squared between two regression models derived from unequal sample sizes?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, regression-coefficients, r-squared

I estimated the variance in an outcome variable (y) that is explained by a predictor variable (x) after adjusting for the three covariates (c1, c2 and c3). 
I derived a full model (y~x+c1+c2) and a null model(y~c1+c2). Then subtracted the $R^2$ of null model from $R^2$ of full model, which gave me the variance explained by x.

I did this in two separate cohorts (sample sizes: A=30,000 and B=600)
I get higher $R^2$ (0.09) in the smaller cohort (B) and slightly lower $R^2$ (0.06) in the larger cohort (A). But the p-value is highly significant in the larger cohort (1e-300) compared to smaller one (1e-12).

If I conclude that the predictor variable x explains larger variance in cohort B compared to cohort A, will it be right?

To make the comparison fair, I sampled 600 random individuals from cohort A and repeated the analysis. This time I get higher $R^2$ similar to what I got for cohort B. I am not sure how to interpret this?